# Difference between window[] and eval() - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been using both in javascript ... really don't know the difference. Googling always shows results for the "window object" or "opening a new window in javascript" so couldn't find anything there.

```
 eval("v"+e)
 window["v"+e]
```

Sometimes window works for me and at other times eval works ....

So what's the difference between eval() and window[] ?

Sorry for the newbie question though !

Norman

Comment: Could you state that as a question, please? Specifically, what are you really asking?

Comment: Whatever the answer, don't use eval!

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that the question is "please explain the situation to me".

Comment: @ jasongetsdown - small question ... why shouldn't eval be used ? Is there a better way to access local variables like so var c = eval("ev"+d); where d=1 locally (this value is passed to a function) and I want to set the value of c equal to the value of local varable ev1 ?

Comment: @Norman: the answer to that is, if you're new and using `eval`, you're probably doing something wrong. Eval does have a purpose, but newcomers probably aren't using it for that.  (this is an old question that was recently brought up, so this question is meant for others)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another point that has not been addressed is that `eval` will resolve the variable reference using the *caller variable environment*, for example:

```
var foo = "global";

(function () {
  var foo = "local";
  alert(eval("foo")); // alerts "local"
  alert(window["foo"]); // alerts "global"
})();
```

So as you can see, is not completely equivalent.

If you simply want to reference a *global variable*, I would recommend you to use the `window[prop]` approach and avoid surprises.

Comment: So in order to access local variables use window otherwise use eval ? ... why do so many people discourage the use of eval? is there another way to access local variables like so eval("ev"+d); where d=1 locally and I want to access the value of local varable ev1 ?

Comment: @Norman, to access global variables use `window[prop]`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) to know why you shouldn't use `eval` when you don't need it..

Answer (score 7):

eval() interprets arbitrary javascript statements, whereas with window you are accessing a property of the window object.

In your example, you seem to be using a property name in both eval() and window[]. As the global scope in a browser is the same as the window object's scope they will evaluate to the same thing.

You can think of your `eval("v"+e)` statement as being equivalent to `eval("window['v'" + e +" ]")`.

Comment: Well put. But to make sure its clear - eval is the bad way to do it; the other is the good way to do it.

Comment: Yes, eval is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Both return a global variable's value. The difference is that if the global variable is undefined, you will get an error on executing eval() whereas window['variableName'] will return undefined(not an error) because accessing an undefined property is not an error but accessing an undefined variable is an error.

Answer (score 4):

`"v"+e` -> string

`eval(x)` -> evaluates the string x, containing javascript expression

`window[x]` -> returns window's property with the same name, as tha value of `x` is. this in fact can be a global variable

therefore, when you have a global variable `v1 = "foo"`, and `e = 1`, then `eval("v"+e)` and `window["v" + e]` both return "foo"