# Add Value Based On Selection

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add the "variable value" to my text area based on the users selection in the drop-down box above.

Here is the code that II have so far:

```
<html>
<head>

<body>

<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="textArray1">text1</option>
    <option value="textArray2">text2</option>
    <option value="textArray3">text3</option>
    <option value="textArray4">text4</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">

var textArray1 = 'this is going to be a long sting of text for text 1 value';
var textArray2 = 'this is going to be a long sting of text for text 2 value';
var textArray3 = 'this is going to be a long sting of text for text 3 value';
var textArray4 = 'this is going to be a long sting of text for text 4 value';

var mytextbox = document.getElementById('mytext');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
      mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
     //mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine, what's your requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making this change in your onchange function:

```
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + window[this.value]; //to appened
```

You could've also used eval() on the this.value, but eval() is about as popular as a red-headed step child. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294262/difference-between-window-and-eval-javascript) question for more info on the differences.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cM5SM/)**